# why does exec env -i /bin/bash in .bash_profile go to background and exit when logging in via su - on arch?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, lfs

I am following the LFS book and trying to get a clean shell using the following .bash_profile in arch (bash 5):

```
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
```

What this usually does is allow logging in via:

```
su - lfs
```

But for some reason, the shell immediately exits and I get:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 su - lfs
```

I am able to get into the session using:

```
fg
```

But then I have to exit twice. The exec and env documentation seem to agree with the LFS provided command that this should just create a bash environment with the 3 variables in it (HOME, TERM, and PS1). How do I get it to just replace bash with the cleaner version and let me log in?

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this?

Comment: Related answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562319/249817).

Comment: @wally Nope, I don't even have my notes for this anymore, but... I found the related answer very informative and figure if I ever run across this again, I'll have a clue!

Answer (score 0):

The bash provided by Arch Linux is compiled with `-DSYS_BASHRC=\'\"/etc/bash.bashrc\"\'` (c.f. its [PKGBUILD](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/bash/repos/core-x86_64/PKGBUILD) file), which means it differs from the bash that is used in LFS because it is influenced by the provided `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

As explained by the added warning at the end of section [4.4 "Setting up the Environment"](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable-systemd/chapter04/settingenvironment.html) this file might influence the lfs user's environment:

> Several commercial distributions add a non-documented instantiation of
> `/etc/bash.bashrc` to the initialization of **`bash`**. This file has the
> potential to modify the *lfs* user's environment in ways that can affect
> the building of critical LFS packages. To make sure the *lfs* user's
> environment is clean, check for the presence of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and,
> if present, move it out of the way.

I am not sure if this is the cause for your particular problem which I cannot reproduce on my Arch Linux system but moving the file out of the way as suggested by the updated LFS instructions might solve your problem.