# Why does my su start in background?

Tags: bash, su

When I use `su - fred` the job is immediately moved to the background. Then, if I use `fg` it works normally:

```
wally@Machine:~$ su - fred
Password:

[1]+  Stopped                 su - fred
wally@Machine:~$ fg
su - fred
fred@Machine:~$
```

Why did it start in the background?

---

Output of `type -a su` (run as wally):

```
su is /usr/bin/su
su is /bin/su
```

---

Output of `jobs -l` (run as wally):

```
[1]+  9187 Stopped (signal)        su - fred
```

---

fred's startup file (`.profile` and `.bashrc` were deleted):

`.bash_profile`

```
exec env /bin/bash
```

---

I found a related question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516888/249817).

Comment: What is the output of `type -a su`?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you reverse the roles of `fred` and `wally`?

Comment: `SIGTTIN` does not cause "`(signal)`".

Comment: @Kusalananda Does not do it if the roles are reversed. If fred does `su - wally` then it starts right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because bash runs the startup files with job control disabled.

Add `set -m` at the beginning of your `~/.bash_profile`.

See also this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476870/308316).

Comment: This worked. I wonder why it has worked in the past without this? I'm using Ubuntu, perhaps something was changed? Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Afair, it has always been that way. I'll add more info to the answer when I get access to the source.